# SQL Query Issue from One-To-Many Relationships

Tags: sql, hibernate, one-to-many

I have to two tables name employee and department. 
My table employee consists of the following columns:

> EmployeeID (PK) | EmployeeName | Department ID (FK)

My table department consists of the following columns:

> DepartmentID (PK) | DepartmentName | DepartmentLocation

Assuming the above is a one-to-many relationships, I am trying to use native SQL Query to retrieve corresponding `DepartmentName` and `DepartmentLocation`  records by `EmployeeName`.

I have tried the following query to execute the above:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID , e.DepartmentName, e.DepartmentLocation 
from Department e WHERE e.EmployeeID = e.DepartmentID
```

I have a POJO class of Employee and Department. I also have a DepartmentManager.java class which uses hibernate. The code are as follows:

**DepartmentManager.java** Enclosed in pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/bF7a13J6

Comment: How're you going to get `e.EmployeeID` field from `Department e` table in your query? There is no such field.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use JPA / JPQL instead of native queries.

However for the statement above you need to query both tables

`SELECT e.EmployeeID , d.DepartmentName, d.DepartmentLocation 
from Department d, Employee e WHERE e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID AND e. EmployeeName LIKE ?1`